# oracle, can select v$session in select statement, but fail when select v$session in trigger

Tags: oracle

in sqldeveloper, under my schema, I can see v$session in public synonyms nodes. I can select it in sql statement also, as follow:

```
select * from v$session;
```

No any error, record retrieved as expected.

Then I create a trigger using same schema (username) as follow:

```
create or replace TRIGGER
TRG_SLIP_DEL
AFTER DELETE ON TABLE_XXX FOR EACH ROW
DECLARE
T_SEQ NUMBER;
.....
BEGIN
......
select start_scnb into T_SEQ
from v$transaction, v$session
where v$transaction.ADDR = v$session.TADDR
and v$session.audsid = SYS_CONTEXT('USERENV','SESSIONID');  
....    
END;
```

then I press run script in sql developer, but error

```
Trigger TRG_SLIP_DEL compiled

LINE/COL  ERROR
--------- -------------------------------------------------------------
18/1      PL/SQL: SQL Statement ignored
19/21     PL/SQL: ORA-00942: table or view does not exist
Errors: check compiler log
```

is shown.

then I right click the TRG_SLIP_DEL trigger and select edit in sqldeveloper, the v$session is red underline with message "PL/SQL:ORA-00942:table or view does not exist",

why?
I can select v$session in select statement before.

[image]

Comment: Have a DBA `GRANT SELECT ANY DICTIONARY TO [trigger owner]` and retry. You probably have this priv only indirectly through a role, and role-based privs aren't honored by stored PL/SQL programs. You need the priv granted directly.